# why can´t I install Cassandra 3.0?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to install Cassandra 3.0, but, when I trying to install it on my PC, it gives me this error:

[Cassandra 3.0 install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32fkX.png)

it says:

```
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
   Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By security means, not all script are enabled to run at powershell. So you should enable powershell to execute that script by running this command:
`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 1):

> Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

This means the Java VM for Cassandra tried to allocate around 2G of heap memory from the operating system, but your operating system was not able to provide that much.

You either have to run C* with a lower heap size setting, free more RAM on the machine, add RAM hardware, or enable/increase swap. For the latter case beware that C* will perform badly if the OS has to swap memory to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on my windows 10, I solved it by running cassandra in an admin command prompt.